# Use the method of moments to estimate the occurrence rate

Tags: statistics

A criminologist is searching through FBI files
to document the prevalence of a rare double-whorl fingerprint.
Among six consecutive sets of 100,000 prints
scanned by a computer, the numbers of persons having the
abnormality are 3, 0, 3, 4, 2, and 1, respectively. Assume
that double whorls are Poisson events. Use the method of
moments to estimate their occurrence rate, λ. How would
your answer change if λ were estimated using the method
of maximum likelihood?

---

i'm having trouble understanding method of moments problems, can someone please solve this so i can backtrack the solution and figure out how to do method of moments problems

(Poisson distribution) $$e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$$